# turtlebot roomba not working

Tags: ros, roomba, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a turtlebot roomba 531 which I am trying to run with a simple launch file as below ;

```
<launch>
  <node name="turtlebot_node" type="turtlebot_node.py" pkg="turtlebot_node">
    <rosparam>
      port: /dev/ttyUSB0
      publish_tf: True
      robot:type: roomba
      has_gyro: False

    </rosparam>
  </node>
</launch>
```

But I get following error message ;

```
"Failed to contact device with error: [Error reading from SCI port. No data.]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.
```

When I try passing roomba opcodes using cutecom on ttyUSB0 @ 115200 baudrate it responds to these opcodes although not exactly like when I send \0x80 it starts cleaning but when I send \0x82 it stops.When I command it to run straight at a certain velocity it again starts cleaning.

Can anybody help me what is the issue with this roomba ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44436/turtlebot-roomba-not-working/) by [BUTT](https://answers.ros.org/users/2372/butt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-09-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a typo in your launch file. It's not `robot:type:` but `robot_type:`.

When working with the roomba, you first need to switch it to the right mode by pressing the on-off key for a while.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem is now solved.The problem was the PL2303 based USB to Serial converter output was not TTL/CMOS compatible so I have now used MAX232 to convert voltage levels to TTL/CMOS levels.Roomba is now working with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [BUTT](https://answers.ros.org/users/2372/butt/) with karma: 31 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1